# How to fix 'Found leak at Activity instance' using LeakCanary

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, leakcanary, android-applicationinfo

I am using Leak Canary to track memory leak and it says leaked at one of **Activity instance**. Can we get exact leak location in that Activity code and what instance means here? How to trace the code to get leak point?

Comment: Follow leakcanary instance tree. You will find clue about whats instance is leaking. Analyse those instance’s references.